# JQuery Console.log each uploaded file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, upload, foreach

I have a AJAX upload form i got it all working and that but all the files upload at once if you select more than one. what i want to do is for each file make a div and show the progress of each file. i have this code here to test the amount of files but it returns 1 everytime in the console.

```
var EachFile = 0
$('#Files').each(function()
{
    ++EachFile;
    console.log(EachFile);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="UForm">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" class="Files" id="Files" name="File[]" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="AB" id="Submit" value="Upload!" />
        <div id="Progress"></div>
        <div class="Caption"><label id="Loaded"></label></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just counting the file input to count the files just use `$('#Files')[0].files.length` or with your own code.

```
var EachFile = 0;
$.each($('#Files')[0].files, function()
{
    ++EachFile;
    console.log(EachFile);
});
```